# Hyperledger Fabric: Is it possible for an organization to join a channel in read only capacity?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, acl, peer

I have tried restricting access by disabling an organisation's ability to invoke chaincode through:
peer/Propose: /Channel/Application/MyPolicy
where

MyPolicy:
    Type: Signature
    Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.admin')"

But this prevents Org2 from querying as well. Is it possible for Org2 to just query without being able to invoke?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could achieve this goal by restricting access to functions in the chaincode itself. With [CID Lib](https://godoc.org/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/lib/cid) you can identify the calling peers (e.g. by their msp) and manage the access based on those information. With that and the concept of AttributeBasedAccessControl you can manage all the access to queries/invokes perfectly on chain and seperate it on peer and organisation level

Answer (score 1):

No. Any member of a channel can query and invoke the instantiated chaincodes.

The only thing you can limit is the [Endorsement policy](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/endorsement-policies.html) - *"which specifies the set of peers on a channel that must execute chaincode and endorse the execution results in order for the transaction to be considered valid*"

Answer (score 1):

All organization in a consortium has same authority on data. So it is not possible to give a org READ access only.
If you really want to do it, how about using private data? Make all data as private data and give authorization to all orgs except the bullied one.

More convenient way would be giving them an intermediate CA server and give only READ access on that chain of trust.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how the intermediate CA server chain of trust work? Also, if I make the data private, the bullied Org wouldn't be able to read as well would it?